# Extract string before and after first forward slash in Excel

Tags: excel, string, text

I have a number of excel cells where I want to grab the text before and after the first forward slash but before the second forward slash AND without the slash itself, for example for the following:

```
M4 HWY/LIZZY DR/CIVIL HILLS
```

I want the following output: `M4 HWY LIZZY DR`

I have the following formula to grab the text before and after the first forward slash but still not sure how to get rid of the slash itself in the output.

```
=MID(A1, 1, FIND("/", A1, FIND("/", A1, 1) + 1) - 1)
```

Comment: For example, `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,1,FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1)-1),"/"," ")`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen!